# Getting an exact match to the string `#deprecated` in Kibana/ELK

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene, kibana, elastic-stack

I'm using Kibana to find all logs containing an exact match of the string `#deprecated`.

[image]

For a reason I don't understand, it matches string with the word "`deprecated`" without the `#` sign.

I tried to use escaping for `#` according to the [Lucene Documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.5/query-dsl-query-string-query.html#query-string-syntax). i.e. `message:"\\#deprecated"` - without change in results.

- How can I query to exact match the `#deprecated` text exact match only
- Why is this happening?

Comment: Try on field "message.keyword" since the # is probably stripped by your analysis chain.

Comment: `message.keyword:deprecated or `message.keyword:*deprecated*` returns nothing, message is indeed an `analyzed` field.

Comment: could you add your index mapping / setting to the question ?

Answer (score 0):

You problem isn't an issue with query syntax, which is what escaping is for, it's with analysis. You analyzer removes punctuation, because it's parsing it as full text. It removes #, in much the same way that it will remove periods and commas.

So, after analysis (assuming standard analysis) of something like: "Class is #deprecated" the token stream generated will have the following tokens: "class", "deprecated" ("is" is a stop word). The indexed form of "#deprecated" and "deprecated" are identical, so it is *impossible* to have a query that can differentiate between them as it is currently indexed.

To fix this you would have to change your [analyzer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-analyzers.html). [WhitespaceAnalyzer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-whitespace-analyzer.html) may be a good choice, and should fix this issue. However, be careful you aren't doing more harm than good. If you use WhitespaceAnalyzer, you are going to have to contend with other punctuation as well, and a search for "sentence"
would not find "match at the end of this sentence.", because of the period. So, if you are searching full text, this will certainly cause far more problems than it solves.

If you want to know the full rules of standard analysis, by the way, it's an implementation of [UAX #29 word boundaries](http://unicode.org/reports/tr29/#Word_Boundaries)